# Assembly stack 3 functions

Tags: assembly, x86

```
aduna2:

.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
.cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    sub esp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 10
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
    add edx, eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+16]
    add edx, eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
    add eax, edx
    leave

aduna:

.LFB1:
.cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
.cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    sub esp, 28
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 7
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax
    call    aduna2
    leave

main:

.LFB2:
.cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
.cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], 6
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], 5
    call    aduna
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    printf
    leave
```

I have the following questions in this code: In the main i cannot figure out where esp goes when sub esp 16 relatively to ebp. This questions i have in "adunare" and "adunare2" .I cannot figure it out where it will be relatively to ebp.I can't figure it out to draw a stack for this program because all my stacks stuck when in "adunare2" i get ebp+8,ebp+12,ebp+16.It will be helpful to show me one because i dont't understand what is going on. And at each call there it is inserted a return address? If yes in "adunare2" how you can get the parameters mentioned up using +8,+12,+16?

Here is the c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int aduna2(int a,int b,int c) 
{
    int d=10;
    return a+b+c+d;
}

int aduna(int a,int b)
{
    int c=7;
    return aduna2(a,b,c);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",aduna(5,6));
}
```

Comment: That disassembly looks incomplete. (I would expect `ret` after `leave`). How did you get it? Isn't it some "smart" disassembler output? Use either compiler listing, or normal disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

Even from the incomplete disassembly I think I can answer the "what does main with stack before aduna":

```
main:
    ; store old ebp value into stack (to restore it before return)
    push  ebp
    mov   ebp, esp   ; copy current value of esp to ebp
```

At this point both esp and ebp have the same value, pointing at the current top of the stack, let's say it's `0x0054`, then the (stack) memory looks like this:

```
address | value
-----------------
0x0050  | ????
0x0054  | old_ebp           <- esp/ebp pointing here
0x0058  | return address to "main" caller
0x005C  | whatever was already in stack before calling main
```

Then the code continues to prepare parameters for "aduna" function:

```
    and   esp, -16     ; -16 = 0xFFFFFFF0 -> makes esp 16B aligned
       ; esp here is 0x0050
    sub   esp, 16      ; make room at top of stack for 16B, esp = 0x0040
       ; store the arguments into the stack
    mov   DWORD PTR [esp+4], 6   ; at 0x0044 goes value 6
    mov   DWORD PTR [esp], 5     ; at 0x0040 goes value 5
    call  aduna                  ; call aduna
```

Now right after entering aduna the ebp/esp and stack memory looks like this:

```
ebp = still 0x0054, nothing did modify it
esp = 0x003C (call did pust return address at top of stack)

address | value
-----------------
0x0038  | ????
0x003C  | return address to instruction after "call aduna" <- esp
0x0040  | 5
0x0044  | 6
0x0048  | ????
0x004C  | ????
0x0050  | ????
0x0054  | old_ebp           <- ebp pointing here
0x0058  | return address to "main" caller
0x005C  | whatever was already in stack before calling main
```

And the `aduna` start with prologue code `push ebp` `mov ebp, esp`, so the top of the stack will change a bit:

```
address | value
-----------------
0x0038  | 0x0054  <- both esp and ebp pointing here (= 0x0038)
0x003C  | return address to instruction after "call aduna"
0x0040  | 5
0x0044  | 6
```

So `mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+12]` will fetch the address 0x0044 (0x38 + 0x0C = 0x44), there's stored 6. `ebp+8` points to value 5. Rest of `esp`/`ebp` combinations in `aduna` points below this, into local variables (which dwell in "stack" part of memory), which I'm not going to describe, as once you understand this initial part, you should be able to decipher the rest of it too.

For `leave` check the instruction set manual (it does change both `esp` and `ebp`). And the missing `ret` is important too, changing `esp` as well.